# How to mock on AndroidJUnit4

Tags: android, junit, mocking, mockito, powermock

I'm new developing android tests, and I'm facing some troubles. I've read the documentation (https://developer.android.com/training/testing/start/index.html). And I've started implementing a test, I guess I need a instrumented unit test (https://developer.android.com/training/testing/unit-testing/instrumented-unit-tests.html) as I need my application context not to be null, but then, how can I mock an object?

I have this:

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)
@SmallTest
public class SplashPresenterImplTest {
    @Mock
    ApiEndpoints api;
    @Mock
    private SplashView splashView;

    private SplashPresenterImpl splashPresenter;

    @Before
    public void setupSplashPresenterTest() {
        // Mockito has a very convenient way to inject mocks by using the     @Mock annotation. To
        // inject the mocks in the test the initMocks method needs to be called.
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);

        // Get a reference to the class under test
        splashPresenter = new SplashPresenterImpl(splashView, api);
    }

    @Test
    public void syncGenres_success() {
        final Observable<List<Genre>> observable =     Observable.just(Arrays.asList(new Genre("trial","trial")));
        when(api.syncGenres()).thenReturn(observable);
        splashPresenter.syncGenres();

        verify(splashView).navigateToHome();
        final List<Genre> genres = SharedPreferencesUtils.getGenres();
        Assert.assertEquals(genres.size(), 1);
    }

    @Test
    public void syncGenres_error() {
        final Observable<List<Genre>> observable = Observable.error(new Throwable());
        when(api.syncGenres()).thenReturn(observable);
        splashPresenter.syncGenres();

        verify(splashView).onError(any(ApiError.class));
    }
}
```

As you can see, I'm testing a simple presenter class but when using MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this); I'm getting an exception:

> java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError at
>   org.mockito.internal.creation.cglib.ClassImposterizer.createProxyClass(ClassImposterizer.java:95)
>   at
>   org.mockito.internal.creation.cglib.ClassImposterizer.imposterise(ClassImposterizer.java:57)
>   at
>   org.mockito.internal.creation.cglib.ClassImposterizer.imposterise(ClassImposterizer.java:49)
>   at
>   org.mockito.internal.creation.cglib.CglibMockMaker.createMock(CglibMockMaker.java:24)
>   at org.mockito.internal.util.MockUtil.createMock(MockUtil.java:33) at
>   org.mockito.internal.MockitoCore.mock(MockitoCore.java:59) at
>   org.mockito.Mockito.mock(Mockito.java:1285) at
>   org.mockito.internal.configuration.MockAnnotationProcessor.process(MockAnnotationProcessor.java:33)
>   at
>   org.mockito.internal.configuration.MockAnnotationProcessor.process(MockAnnotationProcessor.java:16)
>   at
>   org.mockito.internal.configuration.DefaultAnnotationEngine.createMockFor(DefaultAnnotationEngine.java:43)
>   at
>   org.mockito.internal.configuration.DefaultAnnotationEngine.process(DefaultAnnotationEngine.java:66)
>   at
>   org.mockito.internal.configuration.InjectingAnnotationEngine.processIndependentAnnotations(InjectingAnnotationEngine.java:71)
>   at
>   org.mockito.internal.configuration.InjectingAnnotationEngine.process(InjectingAnnotationEngine.java:55)
>   at
>   org.mockito.MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(MockitoAnnotations.java:108)
>   at
>   com.vodity.android.splash.SplashPresenterImplTest.setupSplashPresenterTest(SplashPresenterImplTest.java:45)
>   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) at
>   org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
>   at
>   org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
>   at
>   org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
>   at
>   org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:24)
>   at
>   org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
>   at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325) at
>   org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
>   at
>   org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
>   at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290) at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71) at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288) at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58) at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268) at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363) at
>   org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:128) at
>   org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:27) at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290) at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71) at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288) at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58) at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268) at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363) at
>   org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137) at
>   org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:115) at
>   android.support.test.internal.runner.TestExecutor.execute(TestExecutor.java:59)
>   at
>   android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner.onStart(AndroidJUnitRunner.java:262)
>   at
>   android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:1879)
>   Caused by: org.mockito.cglib.core.CodeGenerationException:
>   java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException-->null at
>   org.mockito.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator.create(AbstractClassGenerator.java:238)
>   at
>   org.mockito.cglib.core.KeyFactory$Generator.create(KeyFactory.java:145)
>   at org.mockito.cglib.core.KeyFactory.create(KeyFactory.java:117) at
>   org.mockito.cglib.core.KeyFactory.create(KeyFactory.java:109) at
>   org.mockito.cglib.core.KeyFactory.create(KeyFactory.java:105) at
>   org.mockito.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.(Enhancer.java:70) ... 43
>   more Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) at
>   org.mockito.cglib.core.ReflectUtils.defineClass(ReflectUtils.java:385)
>   at
>   org.mockito.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator.create(AbstractClassGenerator.java:220)
>   ... 48 more Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: can't
>   load this type of class file at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:300) ... 51 more
>
> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   org.mockito.internal.creation.cglib.ClassImposterizer$3 at
>   org.mockito.internal.creation.cglib.ClassImposterizer.createProxyClass(ClassImposterizer.java:95)
>   at
>   org.mockito.internal.creation.cglib.ClassImposterizer.imposterise(ClassImposterizer.java:57)
>   at
>   org.mockito.internal.creation.cglib.ClassImposterizer.imposterise(ClassImposterizer.java:49)
>   at
>   org.mockito.internal.creation.cglib.CglibMockMaker.createMock(CglibMockMaker.java:24)
>   at org.mockito.internal.util.MockUtil.createMock(MockUtil.java:33) at
>   org.mockito.internal.MockitoCore.mock(MockitoCore.java:59) at
>   org.mockito.Mockito.mock(Mockito.java:1285) at
>   org.mockito.internal.configuration.MockAnnotationProcessor.process(MockAnnotationProcessor.java:33)
>   at
>   org.mockito.internal.configuration.MockAnnotationProcessor.process(MockAnnotationProcessor.java:16)
>   at
>   org.mockito.internal.configuration.DefaultAnnotationEngine.createMockFor(DefaultAnnotationEngine.java:43)
>   at
>   org.mockito.internal.configuration.DefaultAnnotationEngine.process(DefaultAnnotationEngine.java:66)
>   at
>   org.mockito.internal.configuration.InjectingAnnotationEngine.processIndependentAnnotations(InjectingAnnotationEngine.java:71)
>   at
>   org.mockito.internal.configuration.InjectingAnnotationEngine.process(InjectingAnnotationEngine.java:55)
>   at
>   org.mockito.MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(MockitoAnnotations.java:108)
>   at
>   com.vodity.android.splash.SplashPresenterImplTest.setupSplashPresenterTest(SplashPresenterImplTest.java:45)
>   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) at
>   org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
>   at
>   org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
>   at
>   org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
>   at
>   org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:24)
>   at
>   org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
>   at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325) at
>   org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
>   at
>   org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
>   at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290) at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71) at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288) at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58) at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268) at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363) at
>   org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:128) at
>   org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:27) at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290) at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71) at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288) at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58) at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268) at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363) at
>   org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137) at
>   org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:115) at
>   android.support.test.internal.runner.TestExecutor.execute(TestExecutor.java:59)
>   at
>   android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner.onStart(AndroidJUnitRunner.java:262)
>   at
>   android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:1879)

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I get Mockito working in androidTest](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31947878/how-can-i-get-mockito-working-in-androidtest)

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to set up Mockito to work with Android because it uses 'dex' and not 'class' files. See the answer here:

[How can I get Mockito working in androidTest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31947878/how-can-i-get-mockito-working-in-androidtest)